# What is static1.somedomain.com when you browse to a site?

Tags: language-agnostic

Many a times it happens that when I browse to some site, the site brings some content from some other other domain eg. `static1.somedomain.com`

Example: When I browse Facebook it bring some of it's content from `http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/`. What is the actual purpose of this and why don't they put that content on the same domain instead of purchasing a new domain for nothing? Are there any specific advantages to this?

Comment: Maybe you also saw cdn.static.net when you posted this question ! [Read this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/the-speed-of-light-sucks/)

Comment: They didn't purchase it "for nothing".

Comment: Ya, my point is when I browse to some domain it brings data from the domains containing `static`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a static subdomain. The purpose for doing this is that cookies are always sent to the main domain and not alongside of pictures and JavaScript(from the client side). So a client has to transmit less data.

The second thing is that a server which always delivers static contents has different key parameters like IO, memory, CPU as a dynamic node. If you separate servers by static/dynamic you can roll out different scaling strategies.

Comment: So, are these static subdomains free? Where can I get a free subdomain and how do I upload my static photos, pictures etc to these subdomains?

Comment: They are not free you need to purchase at least the toplevel domain. If you have access then to your zonefile you may add any number of subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right forum for your question but this [SO blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/the-speed-of-light-sucks/) answers all you queries